# Oracle VBCS - Implanting esLint and Css Style Lint

Tags: oracle-jet

Look to provide Oracle VBCS with superpowers and coding best practices for the Development Team involved; I'm doing research about implementing Linters for ECMAScript and CSS Code styling in order to have a very healthy and readable code base.

Important dev notes:

- Package.json file present in project structure
- Grunt tech for build project

Have any of you guys implemented something like this?
You considered such a thing could be possible?